# How to add string inside another at a specific position

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a string url containing a link address. I want to check if it's non-www. If it is, then change it to a www link without importing external packages.

from

```
[1] "http://yyyyy.com/xxxx"
```

to

```
[1] "http://www.yyyyy.com/xxxx"
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 s<-c("http://yyyyy.com/xxxx", "http://www.aaaaaa.com/xxxx")
 gsub('(?<=:)(//)(?!www)','\\1www.',s,perl=T)
[1] "http://www.yyyyy.com/xxxx"  "http://www.aaaaaa.com/xxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
s<-"http://yyyyy.com/xxxx"  
s<-ifelse(grepl("www",s),s,gsub("http://","http://www.",s))  
s
```

`grepl("www",s)` checks whether "www" is part of s.
if true, then do nothing. If false use `gsub("http://","http://www.",s)` to replace "http://" with "http://www." in `s`.

Comment: Or just `sub("http://(www\\.|)","http://www.",x)` - or 'find `http://www.` or `http://[anything]` and replace either with `http://www.`

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider making use of the `gsubfn`:

```
my_urls <- c("http://yyyyy.com/xxxx", "http://www.aaaaaa.com/xxxx")
require(gsubfn)
gsubfn(pattern = "http://[^www]", x = my_urls, 
       replacement = function(x) gsub("http://","http://www.",x))
```

The `[^www]` will match all `http://` prefixes that do not have `www` and pass the results to the `gsubfn` that will modify the obtained string. Which would give you:

```
[1] "http://www.yyyyy.com/xxxx"  "http://www.aaaaaa.com/xxxx"
```